# How to arrive from $x^2y^2－x^2－y^2－6xy＋4$ to $(xy＋x＋y－2）(xy－x－y－2）$?

Tags: problem-solving

How do we arrive from

> $x^2y^2－x^2－y^2－6xy＋4$

to

> $(xy＋x＋y－2）(xy－x－y－2）$

?

According to my book these two are equal, but I can't understand how to transform one to another.

Comment: You've been here long enough to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  For a start, enclose mathematical expressions in `$` signs.  `$x^2$` formats as $x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2y^2-x^2-y^2\color{red}{-6xy}+4=x^2y^2\color{red}{-4xy}+4-x^2\color{red}{-2xy}-y^2\\=(xy-2)^2-(x+y)^2=(xy+x+y-2)(xy-x-y-2)$$

Comment: I think it should be $(xy-2)^2$ in the beginning of the second line. Apart from that, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use that $x^2y^2-4xy+4=(xy-2)^{2}$and $(x+y)^{2}=x^2+2xy+y^2.$ So, you have

$$x^2y^2-x^2-y^2-6xy+4=(x^2y^2-4xy+4)-(x^2+2xy+y^2)=(xy-2)^2-(x+y)^{2}. $$

Use the fact that $a^{2}-b^{2}=(a+b)(a-b)$, and you are done

Answer (score 2):

Just splitting the $6xy$ into two parts:
\begin{align}
x^2y^2－x^2－y^2－6xy＋4&=x^2y^2\color{red}{-x^2-y^2-2xy}-4xy+4\\
&=(xy-2)^2-\color{red}{(x+y)^2}=\dotsb
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Notice we have both $x^2$ and $y^2$ with the same coefficient and something of the form $axy$ with a coefficient of the same sign. We can pull out an $(x+y)^2$ from this to get
$$x^2y^2-4xy+4-(x+y)^2$$
Notice now that $x^2y^2-4xy+4$ is $(xy-2)^2$. Then we have
$$(xy-2)^2-(x+y)^2$$
This is a difference of two squares, so we have
$$(xy-2+x+y)(xy-2-(x+y))$$

Answer (score 1):

Start with $$(xy+x+y-2)(xy-x-y-2)=$$

$$ [(xy-2)+(x+y)][(xy-2)-(x+y)]=$$

$$(xy-2)^2-(x+y)^2$$

You can take it from here.